# Verificar si un array esta dentro de una matriz

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo este programa de prueba:

```
array = np.ones((2,2))
print(array)

array2 = np.ones(2)
array2[0] = 2
print(array2)

if array2 not in array:
    print("not in")
```

El resultado es: [[1,1],[1,1]] [2,1]
Lo que quiero hacer es comprobar que [2,1] no esta dentro de esa matriz, solamente se esta comprobando si algún elemento está dentro, pero yo quiero comprobar que el conjunto [2,1] no esté dentro de la matriz.

Comment: Con no está te refieres ¿a que no es una fila de la matriz?, ¿a que no es una columna de la matriz?, ¿a ambas cosas?. ¿Que pasa si tienes  `[[1, 1, 1, 1],[1 , 2, 1,  1]] y buscas si está  [2,1]` ?

Comment: @FJSevilla Exacto, me refiero a que no es una fila de la matriz, es decir, quiero comprobar que [2,1] no pertenezca al conjunto [[1,1],[1,1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El operador `in` actúa mediante el método `__contains__` y NumPy realiza la comprobación sobre todos los ejes, no sobre el eje 1 solamente como hace Python con las listas:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]]
              )

>>> [1, 4] in a
True
```

Una posible solución es usar `numpy.equal` para comparar ambos arrays (la fila y el array a buscar) elemento a elemento y aplicarlo sobre todas las filas del array usando `numpy.all()`:

```
import numpy as np


array = np.ones((2, 2))

array2 = np.ones(2)
array2[0] = 2

if array.shape[1] != array2.shape[0] or not any(np.equal(array, array2).all(1)):
    print("not in")
else:
    print("in")
```